# How can I increment a value on page refresh?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to increase value while page refresh. How can I do?

My code:

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int evrno = 021006;
        string EVRAKNO = "SP-";
        if (Page.IsPostBack == false)
        {
            evrno = evrno + 1;    
        }

        string EvrakNu = EVRAKNO + Convert.ToString(evrno);
        txt_EvrakNo.Text = EvrakNu;    
    }
```

Comment: Actually what u want to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Woring solution:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

        int evrno = 21006;
        string EVRAKNO = "SP-";

        //save initial value in Session
        if (Session["evrno"] == null)
        {
            Session["evrno"] = evrno;
        }
        if (Page.IsPostBack == false)
        {
            //used the value saved in Session
            evrno = Convert.ToInt32(Session["evrno"]) + 1;

        }
        string EvrakNu = EVRAKNO + evrno.ToString();

        //save NEW value in Session again
        Session["evrno"] = evrno;

        txt_EvrakNo.Text = EvrakNu;
        //Response.Write(EvrakNu);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Optimized working code logic

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Set default initial value in session
        int evrno = (Session["evrno"] != null && Session["evrno"].ToString() != string.Empty) ? Convert.ToInt32(Session["evrno"]) : 021006;
        string EVRAKNO = "SP-";
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        { 
            //get value saved in Session
            evrno +=1;
            //set save new value in session
            Session["evrno"] = evrno;
        }
        string EvrakNu = EVRAKNO + Convert.ToString(evrno);
        txt_EvrakNo.Text = EvrakNu;
    }
```

Better approach to do.

Thanks 
Happy coding.

Comment: @emre-aslan: I recommend you to try the optimized way of coding.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Session State for this. Variable on page which you are creating will reset again and again on page load.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(Session["evrno"] != null)
               Session["evrno"] = 21006;
            int evrno;
            string EVRAKNO = "SP-";
            if (Page.IsPostBack == false)
            {
                evrno = Convert.ToInt32(Session["evrno"].ToString());
                evrno = evrno + 1;    
                Session["evrno"] = evrno 
            }

            string EvrakNu = EVRAKNO + Convert.ToString(evrno);
            txt_EvrakNo.Text = EvrakNu;    
        }
```

Comment: it will increase the value on each page load which is of type "GET". it will not increase value on page submit

Answer (score 0):

Your code will give you the same value everytime as you have initialized the variable in `Page_Load`. This event is fired everytime a post back occurs.

Add a hiddenField to the page

`<asp:HiddenField runat="server" id="hdnValue">`

And in Page_Load do this instead of assigning value:

`int evrno = Convert.ToString((hdnValue.Value == ""? "0" : hdnValue.Value));`

Answer (score 0):

You can use property.

```
public int Evrno {get; set;} = 21006;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string EVRAKNO = "SP-";
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        Evnro+=1;    
    }

     // you can add 0 infront of Evnro if it is needed here
     string EvrakNu = EVRAKNO + Convert.ToString(Evnro); 
     txt_EvrakNo.Text = EvrakNu;    
}
```